# OData in ASP.NET Core, pagination with total number of records in a table (Metadat missing)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-odata

I'm using OData in my asp.net core3.1 app and what to delegate the pagination to the client. I'm stuck at how to return alog with the given number of entries, the total number of entries in a table. For example having a table with 100 entries, I want to be able to get this information to know exactly how to create my page component.

Service registration

```
services.AddOData();
```

Configuration

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
    endpoints.Expand().Select().Count().Filter().OrderBy().SkipToken().MaxTop(20);
});
```

This is the endpoint

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var query = dbContext.Users;

    return Ok(query);
}
```

I'm using this query -

`https://localhost:1234/api/users?$count=true&$select=id,name,version&$skip=0&$top=5`

outputs just a list of 5 objects, no extra metadata.

```
[
   {
      Id: "1",
      Name: "a",
      Version: "1"
   },
   ... 4 more objects
]
```

Comment: You should show us a snippet of the results, that URL should be including the result

Comment: I've included a proof in my answer, however your controller logic can greatly affect this, so you should include that in your post too.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, I've updated the quetsion with all the missing information

Answer (score 0):

`$count=true` means that the *overall* count will be in the response:

```
GET: ~/OData/Employees/Summaries?$count=true&$top=10&$skip=10
{
    "@odata.context": "~/odata/$metadata#EmployeeSummaryDTOs(Contact())",
    "@odata.count": 29,
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 15097,
            "Title": "Miss Mavis MOPPIT",
    ...
```

We can actually cheat a little to prove this, if we take the $top 0 records, the count is still returned:

```
GET: ~/OData/Employees/Summaries?$count=true&$top=0
{
    "@odata.context": "~/odata/$metadata#EmployeeSummaryDTOs(Contact())",
    "@odata.count": 29,
    "value": []
}
```

This of course relys on a default or pass through controller, your controller method will need to return an `IQueryable` expression for the `$count` to be resolved automatically.

The default implementation will apply the `$filter` to your expression, then resolve the `$count` as a separate DB query, then it applies the paging Take/Skip logic when it retrieves the final result.

If you are processing the request yourself, then you will need to manage that logic as well.

Comment: On my side, the 2nd odata expression results in an empty array, while the first results in an array with N elements